# Generate Synthetic Data values from existing dataset using distribution of corresponding data columns in Python

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, data-generation

I have a dataset which consists of continuous and categorical data. Total number of datapoints are 145. Now I want to generate more datapoints using this dataset.

It's like how to know the distribution of values in the dataset and generate new values based on this distribution?

The generated synthetic data shall be created from the corresponding distribution of existing data columns.

[Dataset which I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alWzI.png)

I have tried CTGAN, random_choice and Faker methods. But I want python code for generate data points from corresponding distribution of values in the dataset.

Can anyone suggest any method with python code is really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your problem, but I hope it can help and you can adapt it.
Here I fill null values in all the DataFrame columns following the distribution of each column (by the relative frequencies of the different values), so in this case, if you have null values in colA and colB, and colA follows a binomial distribution and colB follows a normal distribution, the function will keep both dist:

```
 def fill_nas_by_proportionality(df, mis_val_table_ren_columns):
    """
    This function performs data completion by normalizing the distribution of each field.
    :param df:
    :param mis_val_table_ren_columns:
    :return:
    """
    for col in mis_val_table_ren_columns.index:
        missing_col = df[str(col)].isnull()
        s = df[str(col)].value_counts(normalize=True)
        df.loc[missing_col, str(col)] = np.random.choice(s.index, size=len(df[missing_col]), p=s.values)
    return df
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html